# Laravel clear file cache

Tags: laravel

I have changed file in Laravel public folder, but when I try to download using link, it downloads old file. I have tried:

> php artisan cache:clear
>
> php artisan route:cache
>
> php artisan view:clear
>
> php artisan config:cache

But without any success. Can someone help me?

Comment: also run this `php artisan route:clear` and then restart your server

Comment: Do you mean you've changed something like a PDF in the `public` directory or is it a PHP file that you're viewing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be your browser that's caching the file. Try download it again in a different browser or try in Incognito or Private Browsing mode to test it. I've had this same thing happen to me today actually and turns out the browser cached the file and kept reloading that file even after it was deleted from the server!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your browser cache not blade cache.

Add a random number or better than that, the current time after the download links. like:

```
return $download_links . '?' . time();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you´re using `artisan` as server try to stop and restart it.
Also you should try to reload the page by `CTRL + F5` or `CTRL + SHIFT + R` which ignores the local browser cache.